# Why do I get the error saying "No value given for one or more required parameters." Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Dim SqlQueryActivity As String = "SELECT * FROM tblActivities WHERE Activity ='" & ActivityCombo.Text & "'AND Sub-Activity = '" & SubActivityCombo.Text & "'"
    Dim DataAdapterActivities As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQueryActivity, conn)
    Dim DataSetActivities As DataSet = New DataSet
    DataAdapterActivities.Fill(DataSetActivities, "ActivitiesData")
    Dim DataTableActivities As DataTable = DataSetActivities.Tables("ActivitiesData")
```

When running the code, I get the mentioned error, pointing to the 4th line where the DataAdapterActivities is filled. I have checked to see that what is in the comboboxes matches records in the database. This sql statement is running before an insert statement to retrieve the appropriate details. I'm trying to understand whether I need to define activitiesdata somewhere seperately, or is it what's being filled. I have opened the connection just before.

Comment: one of the combo's is probably blank.  set a breakpoint and examine the SQL string after you've glued it together

Comment: Google "little bobby tables".  Fixing that nasty problem also allows you to diagnose your bug.

Comment: But I choose the activity and sub activity when running the program in each of the comboboxes

Comment: Breakpoint. Find out what ActCombo.Text and SubActCombo.Text equal.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use a breakpoint, so I comment out the Sql query and insert two message boxes to display the activity and sub activity and they show whichever choices I make in the comboboxes

Comment: Don't concatenate, use parameters. Log your query in a file and test it on the database. I'm pretty sure your dash cause an error, thinking it's a minus. Remove that dash or put the column name in bracket.

Comment: @the_lotus Ok, so I try to update my database in various ways (one of which being changing sub-activity to sub_activity) and even if I save the database, once I reopen it it restores or deletes (displays #Deleted for all the record's fields) some of the records I have changed and changes the field back to sub-activity. At one point trying to update it, overwriting the original file caused it to become corrupt so I could no longer us it. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have to keep the dash, try putting it in bracket. instead of Sub-Activity user [Sub-Activity]

Comment: @the_lotus I'm afraid it still doesn't work, I'm concerned that it is because I forgot to change some of the records in my database manually (which I need to do), and once I try to do it now, cannot get the new one to stick. Keeps restoring back to the older version

Comment: Could it be that I must update the database, and then make a new connection to the project?

Comment: @the_lotus ok, I've got somewhere using the []. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should log your query in a file and try it directly in the database.

This is your query

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivities WHERE Activity ='?'AND Sub-Activity = '?'
```

There's a minus sign in between Sub and Activity. Your database will think you want to substract the column Sub and Activity which I don't think you have since you are getting an error.

I would suggest you rename the column (remove the minus or replace it with something else) in your table

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivities WHERE Activity ='?'AND SubActivity = '?'
```

Or use bracket in your query

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivities WHERE Activity ='?'AND [Sub-Activity] = '?'
```